# Linq to SQL How to write "not-in" query

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have the following 3 tables ( 1 base table and other 2 sattelite tables for each vehicle type.)

**Vehicles**

```
ID      VehicleType
-----------------------------
1       Car
2       Truck
```

**Cars**

```
ID  Make    Model   
-------------------------
1   Toyota  Camry   
2   Honda   Accord
```

**Trucks**

```
ID  Make    Model   
--------------------
1   Ford    F150    
2   Dodge   Ram
```

Then i have corresponding DTO

```
public class VehicleDTO
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int VehicleType {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<CarDTO> Cars {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<TruckDTO> Trucks {get;set;}
}

public class CarDTO
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Make {get;set;}
    public string Model {get;set;}  
}

public class TruckDTO
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Make {get;set;}
    public string Model {get;set;}  
}
```

Then i have list of Vehicle DTO as an argument to the method. I want find vehicles from DTO list that does not exists in the database by matching `Make` and `Model` for that Vehicle Type.
Idea is to then insert the missing vehicles into database.

I have the following query

```
public void FindMissingVehicles(IEnumerable<VehicleDTO> dtos)
{

         var cars = (from dto in dtos
                where !(from c in dbcontext.Cars
                        select new { c.Make, c.Model })
                        .Any(x => dto.VehicleType == 'Car' && dto.Car.Make == x.Make && dto.Car.Model == x.Model)
                select dto).ToList();

 var trucs = (from dto in dtos
                where !(from t in dbcontext.Trucks
                        select new { t.Make, t.Model })
                        .Any(x => dto.VehicleType == 'Truck' && dto.Truck.Make == x.Make && dto.Truck.Model == x.Model)
                select dto).ToList();

    //insert missing cars and trucks into db here

}
```

The query above throws exception

> Message   "Non-static method requires a target."  string

Questions

1> How do i construct this query.

2> Can i make this query `async` by using `AnyAsync` and `ToListAsync`. (I know i have to make method async with Task, and use await inside howevere i could not figure out the async query syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moreover, your approach has performance issue - you perform **N** queries - one for each of `dto`, instead of doing **only two** queries: one for cars and one for trucks:

```
var allCars = dtos.Where(x => x.VehicleType == "Car").ToList()
             .SelectMany(x => x.Cars.Select(y => y.Make + "-" + y.Model).ToList()).ToList();

var existedCars = await dbcontext.Cars.Where(x => allCars.Contains(x.Make + "-" + x.Model))
             .Select(x => x.Make + "-" + x.Model).ToListAsync();

var newCars = allCars.Except(existedCars).Select(x => 
{
    var temp = x.Split('-');
    return new CarDTO 
    {
        Make = temp[0],
        Model = temp[1] 
    };
}).ToList(); 

//exactly same code for Trucks
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of you can't have nested query in linq when one table is from dbContext and the other one is from in-memory enumerable, so if `dbcontext.Cars` and `dbcontext.Trucks` don't have a lot of rows, it's a good idea to load them in memory and use nested query like below:

```
var listCars = dbcontext.Cars.ToList();
var listTrucks = dbcontext.Trucks.ToList();

var cars = (from dto in dtos
            where !(from c in listCars
                    select new { c.Make, c.Model })
                    .Any(x => dto.VehicleType == 'Car' && dto.Car.Make == x.Make && dto.Car.Model == x.Model)
            select dto).ToList();

var trucs = (from dto in dtos
            where !(from t in listTrucks
                    select new { t.Make, t.Model })
                    .Any(x => dto.VehicleType == 'Truck' && dto.Truck.Make == x.Make && dto.Truck.Model == x.Model)
            select dto).ToList();
```